# Was trying to import csv table to Texmaker, the last column gives error when I try to fix the width

Tags: tables, compilation-error, csv, csvsimple, column-width

I was trying to import a csv table to my Tex, with csvsimple. The idea was to fix every column width and make the text wrapped around. However, whenever I change the last column identifier `l` to `p{2cm}` or `>{\centering}p{2cm}`, it gives me error "missing number" and "illegal units of measure

1. Basically this works, but the last column is not at the right width:

```
\begin{table}[h]


\scriptsize
\csvreader[no head, table head =\hline, column count=14,tabular=|>{\centering}m{1.2cm}|c|>{\centering}m{1.6cm}|>{\centering}m{1.6cm}|c|c|>{\centering}m{0.9cm}|>{\centering}m{1.2cm}|>{\centering}m{0.9cm}|>{\centering}m{0.7cm}|>{\centering}m{0.7cm}|>{\centering}m{1.3cm}|>{\centering}m{1.3cm}|l|, late after first line=\\\hline, table foot=\hline]%
{MBxxx210601-01.csv}%
{}
{\csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix & \csvcolx & \csvcolxi  & \csvcolxii & \csvcolxiii & \csvcolxiv & \csvcolxv & \csvcolxvi & \csvcolxvii & \csvcolxviii}


\end{table}
```

2. and after I change the last column identifier like I did for others, it gives error

```
\begin{table}[h]


\scriptsize
\csvreader[no head, table head =\hline, column count=14,tabular=|>{\centering}m{1.2cm}|c|>{\centering}m{1.6cm}|>{\centering}m{1.6cm}|c|c|>{\centering}m{0.9cm}|>{\centering}m{1.2cm}|>{\centering}m{0.9cm}|>{\centering}m{0.7cm}|>{\centering}m{0.7cm}|>{\centering}m{1.3cm}|>{\centering}m{1.3cm}|>{\centering}m{1.3cm}|, late after first line=\\\hline, table foot=\hline]%
{MBxxx210601-01.csv}%
{}
{\csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix & \csvcolx & \csvcolxi  & \csvcolxii & \csvcolxiii & \csvcolxiv & \csvcolxv & \csvcolxvi & \csvcolxvii & \csvcolxviii}


\end{table}
```

The error is a bunch of "missing number" and "illegal unit of measure" alternate.

Anyone has an idea of what the reason could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `\centering\arraybackslash` so that `\\`  retains its end of table roww meaning.

Comment: I tried `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|` It didn't help, with the same error msg.